# GEPlugin doesn't load all data from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, google-earth-plugin

I have a Google Earth Plugin implementation which reads a JSON object from text file and  then displays the positions. The JSON object contains latitude and longitude, but there's a limitation here... If the JSON object becomes larger (number of records) then the globe doesn't pick those records. The JSON object can contains more than 50,000 records, but globe only pick certain amount of records. How do I increase the number of records read by the globe?

The JSON object is like this.

```
{
    "latitude": 32.08546754111066,
    "longitude": -102.88606376716982
},
{
    "latitude": 38.09459585284452,
    "longitude": -106.99208418710695
}
```

I open the JSON file like this.

```
xmlHttp.open("GET", jsonfile, true);
```

The I get the JSON object and load positions

```
if (xmlHttp.status == 200 || xmlHttp.status == 0) {
  var result = xmlHttp.responseText;
  json = eval("(" + result + ")");
}       

loadMarkers();
```

Currently I have 69,000 records (latitude and longitude) in the text file but the Plugin only seems to take 15 000 records.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine that it is something to do with how you are creating the markers from the parsed data. You don't show how you are doing this - what does the `loadMarkers` function look like?

At a guess there is a bottle-neck in that method, it is probably making lots and lots of calls to the Google Earth Api to create all the markers...if so then this could well be the cause of the issue you are having.

If that is the case then I would imagine that using the [google.earth.executeBatch](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/google_earth_namespace#ab26414915202d39cad12bcd5bd99e739) method to execute the body of your  `loadMarkers` function could help you out a lot here. (That is if you aren't already doing exactly that!)

On a side issue, you really shouldn't be parsing JSON using `eval` like that. Eval will parse and execute *any* javascript. You should use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to limit the security risks that eval creates.

Comment: thanks for your response, i count the number of elements in the result variable and the result is "11639".i also changed the code as json=JSON.parse(result). so here why responseText doesnot get 69000 records?is there any limitation with responseText

Comment: what does the loadMarkers function look like?

Comment: its like this                                                      // Create the placemark.
 var lineMark = ge.createPlacemark('');
//add points 
 lineString.getCoordinates().pushLatLngAlt(lat, lng, height))

//add the feature to earth
 ge.getFeatures().appendChild(lineMark);

Comment: Yea, that is almost certainly the issue. You are calling those api methods upwards of 50,000 times sequentially. You should use the executeBatch method to remove the overhead. OOI if you take a look at the object `xmlHttp.responseText` in the debugger is all your data there?

Comment: yes all data is there.i use executeBatch but i couldn't see any performance improvement.i draw 4 lines for each latitude and longitude, i think it takes lot of time.do you know any other method to draw lines on earth without these api methods.var lineMark = ge.createPlacemark('');
var lineString = ge.createLineString('');
lineMark.setGeometry(lineString);

Comment: If you saw no performance improvement then you almost certainly didn't implement it correctly. Rather than going around in circles why not post the code in full? You are essentially asking 'why isn't this working' without ever showing what 'this' is. Please post the full `loadMarkers` function in your question...